# SQL query only display first result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the code below display the row 116 twice, it won't display row 118. Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE dcid IN('116','118')")
        or die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data); 

foreach ($info as $item) {
  echo($item); 
}
```

Comment: Recheck your syntax, use php.net (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), also change to PDO !

Comment: post the table structure and some sample data

Comment: and what $item is expected to be

Comment: You probably got two rows with dcid 116 aand no row for 118

Comment: that because you only fetched once

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_array only fetches a single row. Typically it is used in a while loop to cycle through all the results.

To continue your example above:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE dcid IN('116','118')") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo($item)
}
```

Comment: That does not explain, why the first ID is displayed twice…

Comment: @cbeckner It still display the 116 row twice.

Comment: @AdamSmith When you run the query against the database directly, do you get 2 distinct rows for 116 and 118?

Answer (score 1):

your query must be as:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE dcid IN('116','118')") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo $item['column_name1'];
}   echo $item['column_name2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array returns a single row in an array like this that contains both an associative array and a regular numeric-keyed result set of your row.

```
0=> column,
column=>column
```

Thats why it returns twice in foreach.Use it like this

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Comment: They just come from w3fools and have no idea that _fetch_assoc exists, everyone just comes with _fetch_array while never used it.

Comment: @WigglerJtag is w3tools really advising fetch_array?lulz.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if dcid is your key and it's autoincrementing ( ID for rows ) you can also use LIMIT 116,118.

For more info: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` as this

```
$data =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE dcid IN('116','118') group by dcid")
       or die(mysql_error());
```